# Find and replace specific strings

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string (a tweet) like so:

```
var str = "blah blah blah blah http://example.com blah blah #something blah blah https://example.com blah blah @person"
```

I want to pick out everything that should be a link and wrap it with link tags. The following 4 things need to be found in the string:

- Any word beginning with `@`
- Any word beginning with `#`
- Any word beginning with `http://`
- Any word beginning with `https://`

So I'd image it would be a bit like this:

```
str.replace(regexForHashtag, '<a href="' + linkText + '">" + linkText + "</a>");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to split this string by spaces, and then check whether each substring begins with those things?

Comment: I've used this before: [Parsing Twitter Usernames, Hashtags and URLs with JavaScript](http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/examples/twitter/prototype/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Parsing Twitter Usernames, Hashtags and URLs with JavaScript](http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/examples/twitter/prototype/):

```
String.prototype.parseURL = function() {
    return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&~\?\/.=]+/g, function(url) {
        return url.link(url);
    });
};

String.prototype.parseUsername = function() {
    return this.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function(u) {
        var username = u.replace("@","");
        return u.link("http://twitter.com/"+username);
    });
};

String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
    return this.replace(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function(t) {
        var tag = t.replace("#","%23");
        return t.link("http://search.twitter.com/search?q="+tag);
    });
};

String.prototype.parseTweet = function() {
  return this.parseURL().parseUsername().parseHashtag();
};
```

Which can be called like:

```
var str = "blah blah blah blah http://example.com blah blah #something blah blah https://example.com blah blah @person"

str.parseTweet();
// or:
// str.parseURL
// str.parseUsername
// str.parseHashtag
```

See [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/sonajagafu/1/edit)

Comment: The url to hashtags is outdated, the API now runs on `twitter.com/search?q=%23foo`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following regex:

```
/(?:^|\s)((?:@|#|https?:\/\/)\S+)/
```

The word you need is in group 1.

Comment: Perhaps a word boundary is more useful?

Comment: @CommuSoft: Sorry, I don't get you. Where do you want to put a word boundary?

Comment: before and after, otherwise `"I will work@home"` will be matched as well. The word should start with `@`

Comment: @CommuSoft: But there're no word boundarìes before `@home` in `-@home`. I've modified the answer in order to deal with some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply using a capture group:

```
a = "blah blah blah blah http://example.com blah blah #something blah blah https://example.com blah blah @person";
a = a.replace(/(^|\s)(((https?:\/\/)|[@#])\S*)/g,'<a href="$2">$2</a>');
alert(a);
```

This results in:

```
blah blah blah blah<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> blah blah<a href="#something">#something</a> blah blah<a href="https://example.com">https://example.com</a> blah blah<a href="@person">@person</a>
```

[**JFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5hn04pxe/).

**EDIT**: since usernames and hashtakes should not be copied in the href, you can do it using three stage find-and-replace:

```
a = "blah blah blah blah http://example.com blah blah #something blah blah https://example.com blah blah @person";
a = a.replace(/(^|\s)(https?:\/\/\S*)/g,'<a href="$2">$2</a>');
a = a.replace(/(^|\s)[@](\S*)/g,'<a href="http://twitter.com/$2">$2</a>');
a = a.replace(/(^|\s)[#](\S*)/g,'<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23$2">$2</a>');
alert(a);
```

This results in:

```
blah blah blah blah<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> blah blah<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23something">something</a> blah blah<a href="https://example.com">https://example.com</a> blah blah<a href="http://twitter.com/person">person</a>
```

Comment: OK, but what about the other links I'm looking for? hashtag, username, http links and https link.

Comment: Well according to your question, the href should be `#something` and `@person`. Otherwise you can do it using a three stage replacement. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

@tom your solution will only parse one String at a time. But twitter parse all at the same as you type.

**@Coop want**

1. Any word beginning with @
2. Any word beginning with #
3. Any word beginning with http://
4. Any word beginning with https://

**Here is my approach after playing with this toy [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)** 
**More explanation can be found [here](http://tubentertain.com/web-mobile-application/parsing-twitter-usernames-hashtags-and-urls-with-javascript/)**

```
<div id="element">new text will drop here</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    function convertTextToUrl(refinedText) {
        var refinedText, refinePattern1, refinePattern2, refinePattern3, refinePattern4;
        //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
        refinePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
        refinedText = refinedText.replace(refinePattern1, function(UrlTo) {     
            return UrlTo.link(UrlTo);
        });
         //URLs starting with www 
        refinePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
        refinedText = refinedText.replace(refinePattern2, function(UrlTo) {     
            return UrlTo.link(UrlTo);
        });
        //mention with @
        refinePattern3 = /[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/gim;
        refinedText = refinedText.replace(refinePattern3, function(u) {
            var username = u.replace("@","")
            return u.link("http://twitter.com/"+username);
        });
        //# hastag 
        refinePattern4 = /[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/gim;
        refinedText = refinedText.replace(refinePattern4, function(t) {
            return t.link("https://twitter.com/"+t);
        }); 

        return refinedText;
    }   //USAGE
var TextToUrl= "Tubentertain is a web base #application, kind of a #device such as a #television or #multimedia player that has access to contents residing at remote sites.contact @tubentertain or visit http://tubentertain.com";

    var newText=convertTextToUrl(TextToUrl);
    $("#element").html(newText);
    //========================
});
```

This function can be useful  for many other things  such as converting all similar text on page to urls that link to other content.